# Collection Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I want to write my own Map in Java. I know how map works, but i don't really know where you can keep keys and values. Can i keep them for example in List? So the keys would be store in the list and values would be store in another list?

Comment: Yes, you could do that if you want to. Or you could create a single `List` where each element is a key/value pair (maybe using `MapEntry`). The simplest way to find out is just to try.

Comment: do you mean `write own map implementation` and not using implementations in standard java libraries?

Comment: Yes. That's what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be if you checked out some of the concepts behind HashMap, TreeMap, HeapMap etc. 
Once you understand those concepts, you're far better prepared for writing your own map when it comes to speed.

In other words: unless you know the concepts of all available implementations, it is very unlikely your wheel-re-invention will be a better solution.
Also be sure to test your implementations very thoroughly, as Collection are the backbone and heart of any good application.

Two very very simple (but slow) solutions are these:

1) As suggested above, you can use an `ArrayList<Pair>` and add your custom getItemByKey() (in Java commonly named 'get') method.

2) You can use two arrays, both keeping the same size, and keeping keys and values matched by their respective indices.

Answer (score 0):

For choosing the data structure there's not better than `Array` (not all time but almost) of Entries (key/value) because the main goal of map is to map objects for objects, so mapping keys to values.

Using arrays for fast and constant access O(1), but you have a little problem, when your map is full, you have to create new Array and copy old entries.

Note: `HashMap` works in the same way.